# php sql query in if statement

Tags: php, sql, database, get

$.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url: myurl, dataType:'json', data: 'username',

Comment: Leaving aside the obvious "You should be sanitising your SQL", "You shouldn't be dieing with a query because it exposes your SQL" and various other "not answers" things.

What happens when you do the following:

`<?php`
`if(isset($_GET['username'])`
`{`
`$username = $_GET['username'];`
`if($username == 'ALL')`
`// and so on`
`}`
`else`
`{`
`print_r($_GET);`
`exit();`
`}`
`?>`

Comment: This is wide open door for SQL injections. I suggest you to use mysqli, or pdo prepared statements

Comment: My guess is you are not receiving the dropdown list's value. Can we see the code that creates the dropdown list?

Comment: your data may be in $_POST, what is your form's method attribute set to

Comment: what value u r getting in $username variable ? and check what this expression is returning echo $username=="All";

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do some modifications, if it can work:

I. Take both $_GET and $_POST variables, if your form is using method="POST".

II. Using case insensitive match for "All" string as for all users.

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");
$username = isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username']
  : (isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '');
if(preg_match("/^all$/i", $username))
{
  $query = "select * from broons order by fname asc";
}
else
{
  $query = "select * from broons where username = '$username' order by fname asc";
}
$link = mysql_query($query);
if (!$link) {
  die($query);
}
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($link)) {
  $rows[] = $r;
}
$json = json_encode($rows);

echo $json;
echo $query;
?>
```

Good luck.

ADDED:

I might give a wrong way above.

At the calling side jQuery.ajax(), your username field seems not passed to the server, please try this:

```
$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url: myurl, dataType:'json', data: 'username=JohnDoe2'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the accompanying HTML. It's possible your form is submitting POST variables (recommended) in which case `$_GET['username']` being empty. Does it work with `$_POST['username']`?